# REST call to move a file/folder to another location

Tags: office-365, rest, file, onedrive-for-business

I am trying to move a file/folder from one location to another using a REST call, but I am getting the following error:

```
{
    error: {
        code: "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"
        message: "An unexpected 'EndOfInput' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected."
    }-
}
```

I can successfully run a GET request to get a file/folder, but PATCH is not working.

Here's my headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...g94tP3hkv9g
If-Match: "{8DFE1DAB-D51B-45F9-B181-E9DE3952B407},1"
Body: {"parentReference": {"id": "01J5374RUCQ5Z4U6XLMND3Q4U7GS6JURNJ"}}
```

And here's my endpoint:

```
https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me/files/02KEHFO3NKD7XIYG6V7FC3DAPJ3Y4VFNAH
```

My guess is that the `Body` header is wrong but I have no idea how it should look.

Any ideas?

Comment: OK, so I've established that the JSON needs to be in the payload rather than a body header.! Hopefully I can work the rest out from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the next code:

```
$(function() {
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', CopyFile);
    });

    function CopyFile(){
        var oUrl =  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Library/acento.txt')/copyto(strnewurl='/Lybrary_2/acento.txt',boverwrite=true)";
        $.ajax({
            url: oUrl,
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest":  $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

This code will copy the selected file the new Document Library, overwriting the files if it's exist.
There is another method called MoveTo, the syntax is very similar:

```
/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Shared Documents/filename.docx')
    /moveto(newurl='/Other Folder/filename.docx',flags=1)
```

I hope to be helpful

Comment: Is it possible to move the folder in this way? My folder is having multiple folders and multiple documents inside it.